# REACT: How to use a variable defined inside .env file?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, jsx

How can I use a variable that is defined inside .env. For example if I declare a variable named `REACT_APP_ONLINE_STATUS_TIME_MINUTES=5` can I use it in by jsx as a conditional variable like
`online_time < ONLINE_STATUS_TIME_MINUTES` What steps do I need to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)?

If that's the case, then you can add pretty much any variable in your `.env` file.

However, **your variable MUST start with the prefix** `REACT_APP_`.

Then in your code, you can access your variable easily using `process.env`.

For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        {online_time < process.env.REACT_APP_ONLINE_STATUS_TIME_MINUTES
            && <MyOtherComponent />}
    );
}
```

Here, the `MyOtherComponent` is rendered only when the condition `online_time < process.env.REACT_APP_ONLINE_STATUS_TIME_MINUTES` is `true`.

If you're not using create-react-app, you may want to use [react-scripts](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts).

Comment: Hi @Fahad Munir if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) library.

See the usage here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage

> process.env now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file.